# Android Studio TextView timer switch but with text

Tags: java, timer, textview

I am trying to create an instance where the TextView will say "UP" and then "DOWN" when clicking start. rigth now i have a timer in place already. I am trying to keep them both connected. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get reference of the XML layout's widgets
    final TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    final Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
    final Button btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.psbutton);
    final Button btnResume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rsbutton);
    final Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

    //Initially disabled the pause, resume and cancel button
    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
    btnResume.setEnabled(false);
    btnCancel.setEnabled(false);


    //Set a Click Listener for start button
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            isPaused = false;
            isCanceled = false;

            //Disable the start and pause button
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnResume.setEnabled(false);
            //Enabled the pause and cancel button
            btnPause.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);

            CountDownTimer timer;
            long millisInFuture = 120000; //2mins
            long countDownInterval = 1000; //1 second


            //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
            timer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,countDownInterval){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    //do something in every tick
                    if(isPaused || isCanceled)
                    {
                        //If the user request to cancel or paused the
                        //CountDownTimer we will cancel the current instance
                        cancel();
                    }
                    else {
                        //Display the remaining seconds to app interface
                        //1 second = 1000 milliseconds
                        tView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        //Put count down timer remaining time in a variable
                        timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
                    }
                }
                   public void onFinish(){
                    //Enable the start button
                    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
                    //Disable the pause, resume and cancel button
                    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
                    btnResume.setEnabled(false);
                    btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

    //Set a Click Listener for pause button
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //When user request to pause the CountDownTimer
            isPaused = true;

            //Enable the resume and cancel button
            btnResume.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);
            //Disable the start and pause button
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnPause.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    //Set a Click Listener for resume button
    btnResume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Disable the start and resume button
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnResume.setEnabled(false);
            //Enable the pause and cancel button
            btnPause.setEnabled(true);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);

            //Specify the current state is not paused and canceled.
            isPaused = false;
            isCanceled = false;

            //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
            long millisInFuture = timeRemaining;
            long countDownInterval = 1000;
            new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval){
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    //Do something in every tick
                    if(isPaused || isCanceled)
                    {
                        //If user requested to pause or cancel the count down timer
                        cancel();
                    }
                    else {
                        tView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        //Put count down timer remaining time in a variable
                        timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
                    }
                }
                public void onFinish(){

                    //Disable the pause, resume and cancel button
                    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
                    btnResume.setEnabled(false);
                    btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
                    //Enable the start button
                    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.start();

            //Set a Click Listener for cancel/stop button
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    //When user request to cancel the CountDownTimer
                    isCanceled = true;

                    //Disable the cancel, pause and resume button
                    btnPause.setEnabled(false);
                    btnResume.setEnabled(false);
                    btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
                    //Enable the start button
                    btnStart.setEnabled(true);


                }
            });
        }
    });

    //Set a Click Listener for cancel/stop button
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //When user request to cancel the CountDownTimer
            isCanceled = true;

            //Disable the cancel, pause and resume button
            btnPause.setEnabled(false);
            btnResume.setEnabled(false);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(false);
            //Enable the start button
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Welcome, what is the question ? Please explain the problem.

Comment: I am trying to make my textview "Up" change every second to go back and forth between Up and Down

Comment: But that is not a question, just a requirement. What is wrong in your code? What is happening (or not happening). Please see [ask]